# Is there a way to render color using the interweave library in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the interweave library in React to render a string of HTML code, but it does not render color (the style tag is not supported since it is technically CSS, not HTML). Does anyone know a way to get color to render through the library, maybe with an alternative tag? The "font" tag is also unsupported.

Background: I am getting a string of HTML text from the server-side of an application and trying to render the HTML of the resulting string variable on the front-end).

Link to the Interweave library: https://github.com/milesj/interweave

```
import React from "react"
import { Markup } from 'interweave';

export default class Formating extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <Markup content={this.props.string}/>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the transform prop provided by interweave, a quick example to highlight text within `<b>` tags below:

```
import React from "react"
import Interweave, { Node } from 'interweave';

export default function MyComponent(props) {

    const transformText = (node: HTMLElement, children: Node[]):React.ReactNode => {
        if (node.tagName.toLowerCase() === "b") {
        return <span style={{backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>{children}</span>;
    }
  };

    return(
        return <Interweave content={props.string} transform={transformText}/>
    )
}
```

See https://interweave.dev/docs/parser#replacing-elements

Comment: Important to cast the node.tagName to lowercase as @Oscar Chen say so it can recognised the element.